# Does the responsivity change with temperature of a pin photodiode?

Tags: photodiode

I have a more fundamental question on which I can not find any answer, maybe there is some inherent understanding I am missing. I am currently trying to evaluate the temperature behaviour of a InGaAs pin-photodiode. What I often find is that the dark current increases with temperature. I also know that thermal noise increases with temperature. But what about the photocurrent itself? Does the noise-free photocurrent change with temperature? In some datasheets I find that the responsivity only changes significantly at the upper detection edge, does this result from a temperature dependency in the photocurrent or are the other currents responsible for that?

Answer (score 3):

> In some datasheets I find that the responsivity only changes significantly at the upper detection edge, does this result from a temperature dependency in the photocurrent or are the other currents responsible for that?

This is typical. The responsivity is normally not particularly sensitive to the device temperature.

But for photon energy very close to the band gap energy, it may be sensitive because the band gap energy itself has some temperature dependence.

Comment: Temperature in semiconductor detectors increase intrinsic concentration of carriers (holes and electrons), which are source of dark current noise.

Comment: @www.Photin.eu, that affects sensitivity, not responsivity.